# Splitting .txt of integers into list Python

Tags: python, list, split, hashcode

I am considering doing the [Google Hash Code](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/hashcode?show=progress), but am running into some issues on the *practice problems*! The problem is order a number of pizza slices without going over the limit. The input gives you the different quantities of slices for each type. This is the c_medium.in input file:

```
4500 50
7 12 12 13 14 28 29 29 30 32 32 34 41 45 46 56 61 61 62 63 65 68 76 77 77 92 93 94 97 103 113 114 114 120 135 145 145 149 156 157 160 169 172 179 184 185 189 194 195 195
```

To determine my options for sizes, I am using this code:

```py
file = open('c_medium.in','r')
raw_pizza_types = file.readline(2)
pizza_types = raw_pizza_types.split()
print(pizza_types)
max = file.readline(1)
def solution() -> None:
  #pizza_types = [int(i) for i in pizza_types] # will loop through strings and convert them to ints 
  pass
```

This code should print out a list with the number of slices on different pies, but instead simply prints out `['45']`. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: are you just trying to read the second line of the file only?

Comment: You should really use a context manager to handle file objects. It isn't clear to me what exactly you're trying to do. The topic of simple file IO has been covered many times on here.

Answer (score 2):

the parameter in `readline()` indicates size to be read, not the number of lines to be read. So you're telling it to read in only the first two characters, which are 45 and then stop.

What you want to be doing is using the command `readlines()`, which by default reads in all lines as a list. You would then just have to process the data out of the list. I would recommend something along the lines of:

```py
file = open('filename', 'r')
raw_pizzas = file.readlines()
slices = []
for p in raw_pizzas:
    for s in p.split():
        slices.append(s)
print(slices)
```

please note that this is meant as more of pseudocode, I have not tested to make sure it works as written.

Comment: Not that it matters in this case, but the `size` parameter for [`io.TextIOBase.readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.readline) is the number of characters, not bytes. In Python 2 it was the number of bytes.

Comment: Best practice is to use a `with` statement to read a file: `with open('filename', 'r') as file: raw_pizzas = file.readlines()`

Answer (score 1):

The `readline` method's parameter is `size` and does not read the second line, which I'm assuming is what you want to do. File-handles are iterators, and can't go back to a previous line unless you `seek`. So I would read in your variables in the order that they appear in the file:

```py
# the with statement is the pythonic way to open files
# since you don't need to remember to close them
with open('c_medium.in','r') as fh:
    # read the first line to max, but max itself is a function
    # so we will name it something else
    maximum_slices = [int(x) for x in next(fh).split()]

    # this will split the second line on any whitespace character
    pizza_types = next(fh).split()
```

Your list comprehension should be perfectly sufficient after that. I am also assuming that the `maximum_slices` should also be a list of integers